# Browser is redirected to service-worker.js

Tags: spring, spring-boot, polymer, vaadin, service-worker

I'm developing two separate projects: one is `Polymer` app with `Service worker`(scaffolded with Polymer CLI) and second app is `Spring Boot` with `Vaadin` and its itegration library `Vaadin Spring`. Both applications are running on `localhost:8080`.

On SpringBoot app, non-authenticated user is redirected to `/login`. After successful authentication user should be redirected back to `/`, but instead is redirected to url `http://localhost:8080/service-worker.js`, where is displayed default spring `404` page. When I manually change url back to `/`, SpringBoot app is working again.

- this behavior occured after I was working on Polymer app and switched to SpringBoot
- tested on Chrome and Firefox
- clearing browser cache helps
- Vaadin is also using hashbang

I can't find source of the problem (if is it Polymer or SpringBoot+Vaadin) and clearing cache or manually changing URL every time is frustrating.

**EDIT:**

I'm using default handler `SavedRequestAwareVaadinAuthenticationSuccessHandler` provided by `Vaadin Spring`. It should redirect back to previous URL or  to fallback URL `/`.

```
@Bean(name = VaadinSharedSecurityConfiguration.VAADIN_AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS_HANDLER_BEAN)
VaadinAuthenticationSuccessHandler vaadinAuthenticationSuccessHandler(@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection") HttpService httpService, VaadinRedirectStrategy vaadinRedirectStrategy) {
    return new SavedRequestAwareVaadinAuthenticationSuccessHandler(httpService, vaadinRedirectStrategy, "/");
}
```

Comment: Please post your code that redirects after login.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. This is a browser thing, and you can't do noting from your application or on server side.

I solved ti by deleting service worker for localhost adress in chrome manually.

You can do it by opening developer tools in chrome -> Tab Resources -> Service Workers
Find your service worker on specific url, for example http://localhost:8080/login and delete it.

Another alternative is to use different localhost (localhost, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.2) IP addresses for developing polymer application and Vaadin application.

Answer (score 3):

I Soleved it. 
Go to locahost:8080/login -> Inspect (ctr+shift+I) -> Application tab -> choose Service Worker and unregister sw.js
Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that to access the "service-worker.js" authentication is needed, and since this "service-worker.js" is accessed automatically in each change and replaces the session attribute SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST, a simple solution is to give public access to it:

```
 http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/service-worker.js").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/**").fullyAuthenticated().and()
```

Comment: I am sorry, but for this scenario your answer is incorrect. You've probably missed first crucial part - " I'm developing two separate projects ... ".